# A non-recoverable sign in failure occurred in API 16

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have a React native project with Firebase. I have created a sign in with Google which it works on API 29 and API 19. But I got **"A non-recoverable sign in failure occurred"** error when I try to login with android API 16 (Also tested with same error on a real device with API 18).

I have done all the settings are required (Because of that I'm able to login with other APIs).
Is there anything else I have to consider regarding API 16?

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3")

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that it's compatible with andorid 16, the library i mean, sometimes the minSDK required by the library is more than 16

Comment: I'm using react-native-community/google-signin and no where is mentioned about the minSDK